# Within Judaism is there a tradition of interpreting individual letters such as with YHVH

Tags: words, aleph-bet-letters

Two recent questions on Christianity Stack have got me thinking about the way some people interpret the divine name.  One answer gave this interpretation:

```
Yod - י Hand
Hey - ה Open Window, to reveal
Vav - ו Nail / Tent peg
Hey - ה Open Window, to reveal
```

Another answer came up with this interpretation:

Hey = Behold
Vav = Nail
Yod = Closed Hand

I would like to know if this interpretation of Hebrew letters is accepted within Judaism and also something about the history of ascribing meaning to letters.

This is my first venture into Mi Yodeya so please be kind - I have a genuine interest in this subject and would like to know more. Also, I have no idea which tags to use, so any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Lesley. The letter Vav doesn’t mean nail or Tent Peg, which is actually associated with weapons of war and violence (יתד). Vav, which literally means Hook, has a connotation of joining together which is why it is also part of the word Mitzvot (מצות). Through the commandments, one connects with the Creator, the source of all life.

Comment: What brought you to the Christianity Stack? And as a follow up to that, what brought you to Mi Yodeya?

Comment: Did you know that in Judaism everyone is free to offer his own interpretation? Beware, there are no guidelines and no litmus tests to tell the good from the bad. And my advice - don't jump straight to interpreting the Divine name, start with something handy, like domestic animals - can you interpret their names in Hebrew?

Comment: @Yaacov Deane Thanks for your comment. I came to Christianity Stack to ask questions and find answers on Christian theology and to better understand the differences between various denominations.  However, C.Stack does not help with understanding Judaism or Hebrew, so I came to Mi Yodeya in the hope of being enlightened. I became a Christian (of the Protestant persuasion) 23 years ago. There is much I do not know and I am not ashamed to admit my ignorance, especially when it comes to Judaism and the Hebrew Scriptures.

Comment: @Al Berko How refreshing to be allowed to interpret freely, but then how do you decide which view is right? Alas, I know nothing about the Hebrew language, which is why I have come to Mi Yodeya. There's a lot of stuff "out there" on various meanings of the Tetragrammaton and, as a Christian, I am curious to seek an authentic view, hopefully with links to reliable sources.

Comment: So would it be accurate to say that you are simply doing some kind of comparative religious study in the hope that it gives you a more clear understanding of how to be a better Christian?

Comment: @Yaacov Deane No, there's more to it than "simply doing some kind of comparative religious study" because head knowledge does not necessarily result in changed behaviour, behaviour that is pleasing to our Creator. We are to engage our intellects, it is true, but any knowledge has to permeate into our hearts so that we gain a better understanding of G-d's will for us. I seek to become a better person in G-d's eyes. Religion does not save anybody. But it's always good to base knowledge on truth, and that comes from G-od's Word. Does my denomination matter?

Comment: In Judaism, there's no true and false but popular and unpopular. Rabbis are measured by their popularity and the number of their followers. So don't expect to hear one "true" meaning of anything Jewish.

Comment: From the Guidelines for being Off-Topic: "On the other hand, questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are about...

other religions
Hebrew language
Jews, Jewish history, and Israel
... (examples) are generally off-topic."

Comment: @Yaacov How is interpretation of the letters of Hashem’s Name off topic? I see some people voted to close as comparative religion, and I’d like to remind such people that that close reason requires that the question require knowledge of other religions, which isn’t applicable here.

Comment: @DonielF I take it you are missing the whole idea of being 'nailed to the cross through his hands and feet' (meaning the cruxifiction) and how that is by association relating to G-d (shem Havayah) and revealing that Yushkie is in fact god incarnate. Good Jews, please hear the good news and see the light....Vote to close.

Comment: @YaacovDeane You’re correct, I did indeed miss that. Comparative religion it is.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic.  The asker heard an interpretation (which is *wrong* and a Christian attempt to inject Jesus into the torah) and came here to ask about the technique being used.  I see this as a question about whether we do that kind of alef-bet wordgame interpretation.  Answers would be free to debunk the specific example or ignore it and answer the general question.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Nothing in this question requires anyone to compare any religions. The fact that the *motivation* for the question may involve another religion is not relevant.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The risk with entering this type of territory and allowing the question to be posted, is because Jewish laypeople, people who are young or without much knowledge can take such discussion as potentially legitimate and worth considering.  That type of doubt is what evangelizing to the Jews works for. It is not in any way traditional Jewish teaching or belief. It belongs in a comparative religion stack or a language stack.

Comment: @Yaacov Deane The "risk" with allowing this question is that by avoiding a straight answer to a straight question by removing the question is you disallow the opportunity to promote a good reason for proving the interpretation I found is rubbish and invalid. Is the interpretation I found valid or not?  If not, why not? You said "it is not in any way traditional Jewish teaching or belief." How?  I'm listening and waiting. I have not made any assumptions or drawn any conclusions. But I am curious as to why you want to close this question down.

Comment: @Lesley My 1st comment to you answered your question and yes, what is being passed off to you as the mystical understanding of G-d’s name as sourced in your question is rubbish. All the inner teachings the Jewish people have today concerning the meaning behind the letters, crowns and nekudot come to us via Moshe, like the rest of the Torah. It isn’t something made up by someones creativity. But the hostility you express now reveals your intent is not benign. The moderators should take note. This question should be closed.

Comment: @Yaacov Deane Thank you for providing me with an answer to my question.  That is all I wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only example I remember of interpreting the Hebrew letters comes in the Talmud [Shabbos 104a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.104a?lang=bi). Here is the beginning of the first exposition (please read the rest from the link).

> The Sages said to Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi: Young students came today
>   to the study hall and said things the likes of which were not said
>   even in the days of Joshua bin Nun. These children who only knew the
>   Hebrew alphabet interpreted the letters homiletically.
>
> Alef beit means learn [elaf] the wisdom [bina] of the Torah. Gimmel
>   dalet means give to the poor [gemol dalim]. Why is the leg of the
>   gimmel extended toward the dalet? Because it is the manner of one who
>   bestows loving-kindness to pursue the poor. And why is the leg of the
>   dalet extended toward the gimmel? It is so that a poor person will
>   make himself available to him who wants to give him charity. And why
>   does the dalet face away from the gimmel? It is to teach that one
>   should give charity discreetly so that the poor person will not be
>   embarrassed by him.

The thought is an understanding of the Hebrew alphabet but not a key to interpreting the letters in different words.

Later on in the same passage, the letters are interpreted in a different way:

> The Gemara cites another midrash that also deals with the letters of
>   the alphabet. This one uses a code in which the first letter is paired
>   with the last letter, the second letter with the penultimate one, and
>   so on [alef tav, beit shin]. Alef tav, God said: If he despised Me
>   [oti ti’ev] would I desire [etaveh] him? Beit shin: If he does not
>   desire to worship Me [bi], shall My name [shemi] rest upon him? Gimmel
>   reish: He defiled his body [gufo]; shall I have mercy [araḥem] on him?
>   The word comprised of the letters gimmel and reish in Aramaic means
>   licentiousness. Dalet kuf: He locked My doors [daltotai], shall I not
>   cut off his horns [karnav]? To this point, the Gemara interpreted the
>   letters as referring to the attribute of the wicked.
>
> However, with regard to the attribute of the righteous it is taught
>   differently. Alef tav, beit shin: If you have shame [ata bosh], gimmel
>   reish, dalet kuf: If you do so, you will reside [gur] in the heavens
>   [bedok], as the verse says: “Who stretches out the Heavens like a
>   curtain [dok]” (Isaiah 40:22). Heh tzadi, vav peh: There is a
>   partition [ḥatzitza havei] between you and anger [af]. Zayin ayin, ḥet
>   samekh, tet nun: And you will not be shaken [mizdaze’a] by the Satan.
>   Yod mem, kaf lamed: The minister of Gehenna said before the Holy One,
>   Blessed be He: Master of the Universe, send the righteous as well into
>   the sea to which all go [yam kol], Gehenna.

(see the link for more examples.) Again this does not provide an interpretative tool for use generally.

Comment: Also [Bereshit Raba 1:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.1.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Comment: Thank you for your response which I am pleased to accept before this question is closed down as "off topic."

Comment: @Lesley That's generous of you.

Comment: You are most welcome.  Seems like asking questions on Mi Yodea is even more tricky than asking questions on Christianity Stack.  However, if at first you don't succeed... give up?  Only joking.  Shalom.